# Travis CI, Atoum and Coveralls for a PHP project

Tags: php, travis-ci, coveralls, atoum

Fairly new to the CI game. I'm trying to get Travis CI and Coveralls working together and having a bit of trouble with it. The project in question is written in PHP and being tested with Atoum. My current .travis.yml file contains the following and currently all builds are passing:

```
language: php
php:
  - "5.4"
  - "5.5"
  - "5.6"
  - "nightly"
before_script: wget http://downloads.atoum.org/nightly/mageekguy.atoum.phar
script: php mageekguy.atoum.phar -d tests
```

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my coverage data over to Coveralls. One example script given on the Coveralls page involves using an Atoum config file and specifying your Coveralls Project Token, but then continues to say you need to keep this private. I don't see how that'll work, as in my case as the project I'm working on is open source.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](https://github.com/estvoyage/statsd/blob/master/.atoum.php) a valid .atoum.php which handle Travis and Coverall.

Comment: Sweet, the script works well, except I seem to get an error on some builds: `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
 in phar:///home/travis/build/xxx/yyy/mageekguy.atoum.phar/1/classes/adapter.php at line 18` Any ideas? If I log into Travis-CI and re-run the particular job that failed, it seems to work the second time round.